# How to check if my model has changed on the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update a list of items. But I want to update only the items that have changed on my view.

For now, on my controller I have this code

```
foreach ( var item in items )
{
   update(item);
}
```

But I need to have something like that

```
foreach ( var item in items )
{
    if(ItemHasChanged(item))
    {
       update(item);
    }
}
```

I need to have this because I don't want to do any unnecessary updates and it's good for performance. Also I don't want to do a roundtrip to database to check if the item has changed.

**Is it possible to check on the view if the item has changed ?**

I am using asp.net mvc 4...

Comment: If your model contains a property, say `bool IsDirty`, you could use javascript to check the controls for each property of the model and compare the actual `value` with the `defaultValue`, then update the `IsDirty` property if any of them are different.

Comment: ok.. so the only way to do it is with javascript ?

Comment: ok then.. i'll try it that way..

Comment: You could also recreate the original model (given to the view) and compare it with the bound model (given from view) by overriding the equals-methode of the model class. But don't know if this would improve performance.

Comment: @StefanP. best approach in my opinion is the one introduced by Stephan Muecke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could cache your model before to send it to the view.

HttpContext.Current.Session["OldModel"] = yourModel;

And then compare the model you get in your POST action with the one is cached.

If you decide to do it by JavaScript I think you should take into consideration that a user could modify or disable the JavaScript on the browser.

Answer (score 4):

The below jQuery will do this job. As any of the input field is changed in the View this function would be triggered.

```
$('form :input').on('change input', function () {
    alert('changed'); //Your code..        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if the form contains other type of HTML  elements which are not input type and user can interactive with like Select, TextArea and so on?